# Using a method to output the area of a circle

Tags: java, methods

My question has two parts.

1. Write a method called area, that takes in the radius of a circle as
   input, and outputs the area of the circle.
2. Using one line of code, call the circleArea method with a radius of
   5.2, storing the output in a variable.

For number 1, i have:

```
public static area(double radius) {
    double circleArea = (radius) * (radius) * Math.PI;
    return circleArea;
}
```

Does that look right?

Also, can someone help me with number 2, I have no idea how to do that with only one line of code.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thats wrong the function doesnt have the return type.

Calling the code will be something like...

```
public class CalculateArea {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double area = areaCircle(5.2);
    }

    public static double areaCircle(double radius){

        double circleArea = (radius) * (radius) * Math.PI;
        return circleArea;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what about number 2? Would it be: double oneLiner = circleArea (5.2);

Answer (score 0):

For #2:
Yes, `double oneLiner = circleArea(5.2);` is good enough. I have removed the space between function name and the parenthesis.